# Showing that the diagonal is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having some trouble with this problem:

Let $G$ be some group and let $H \subseteq G \times G$, where $H = \{(g, g) \mid g \in G\}$. This is sometimes called the *diagonal subgroup* of $G \times G$. Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G \times G$.

Is it because all elements of $G \times G$ can be written as ($g, g$), and that is the definition of $H$? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: No, elements of $G\times G$ are of the form $(g_1,g_2)$ with $g_1,g_2\in G$.

Comment: But isn't that the definition of $H$? That it consists of two elements from $G$?

Comment: @Max, no.  The definition of $H$ is that it consists of pairs of two *identical* elements of $G$.  Let $G = {\bf Z} / 5 {\bf Z}$.  You can sketch $G \times G$: it will be a 5-by-5 grid.  $H$ is the diagonal of that grid.

Comment: So how would I go about proving this? My thinking was that ($g, g$) $\in$ $G \times G$, so $H$ must be in $G \times G$ and therefore a subgroup.

Comment: Let's rephrase. $G \times G = \{(g_1,g_2) \mid g_1,g_2 \in G\}$ is the set of all pairs of elements of $G$, and $H = \{(g_1,g_2) \mid g_1,g_2 \in G \text{ and } g_1 = g_2 \}$ is the set of all pairs where the two elements are equal.

Answer (score 1):

It is taken that $G \times G$ is a group.

Since $H = \{(g,g) \in G \times G \mid g \in G \}$, we define for $h_1, h_2 \in H$

$ h_1 h_2 = (a , a) (b , b) = (ab , ab)$.

Now we show $H $ meets the definition of a group.

Associativity comes from $G \times G$.

$(e,e) $ is the identity element, since $(e,e)(a,a) = (ea,ea) = (a,a) $.  Similarly $(a,a)(e,e) = (a,a) $

For $ab=c $ where $a,b,c \in G $, then $(a,a)(b,b)=(c,c)$ shows closure.

For every $(a, a) \in H, \exists \ a^{-1} \in G$ s.t. $(a^{-1}, a^{-1}) \in H $ and $(a, a) (a^{-1}, a^{-1}) = (e,e) $.

Thus $H $ is a subgroup of $G \times G$.

Comment: Maybe you have to recall the definition of a subgroup.

Comment: No I did it long form on purpose. If the OP struggled with this question it shows they don't understand group definitions well enough yet to take short cuts.

Answer (score 0):

We can skip the whole rigamarol of testing all axioms by noticing that $\Delta:G\to G\times G$ defines as $\Delta(g)=(g,g)$ is a homomorphism, injective and surjective to $H$ so it is a subgroup, and to see a proper subgroup you use the projective homomorphism and the fact it isnt injective.

Comment: So how do you prove that this is a homomorphism other than effectively doing the same proof that directly shows that $H$ is a subgroup?

Comment: Your answer is more cumbersome that the straightforward proof that $H$ is a subgroup when need to show only **one** thing: if $x,y\in H$ then $xy^{-1}\in H$.